# Minimum API for DatePicker

Tags: android, datepicker, datepickerdialog

I'm testing just a sample of code in order to implement in other app, but I have got an error saying that the minimum API required in order to use getInstance() is 24, and I'm current using API 16. But I had searched on the Internet and it appears that this can be used since API 1 O.o Can I ignore this error?

```
import android.app.DatePickerDialog;
import android.icu.util.Calendar;
import android.support.annotation.RequiresApi;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.DatePicker;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    DatePickerDialog datePickerDialog;
    EditText date;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        date = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.date);

        date.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){


            @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                final Calendar c;
                c = Calendar.getInstance();
                int mYear = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
                int mMonth = c.get(Calendar.MONTH); 
                int mDay = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH); 
                //Dialog DatePicker
                datePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(MainActivity.this, new
                DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener(){
                    @Override
                    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view,int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth){
                        date.setText(dayOfMonth + "/" +(monthOfYear + 1) + "/" + year);
                    }
                },mYear,mMonth,mDay);
                datePickerDialog.show();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Replace:

```
import android.icu.util.Calendar;
```

with:

```
import java.util.Calendar;
```

Comment: Thank you! I could not believe that was just this... I'm starting with Android development

Comment: @ViníciusGhietti: Yes, this is an all-too-easy mistake to make, as the IDE import-assistant code thinks that both are equally likely choices.